# C - Implementation of Binary Tree Causing Strange Behavior on Insert

Tags: c, recursion, binary-search-tree, dynamic-memory-allocation, function-definition

I have my binary tree setup like this:

```
`
```

I also initialize the first node of the BT like so:

```
`
```

Everything works fine up to this point. However, when I try to insert into my BT, I keep getting unexpected behavior. My insert function looks like this.

```
`
```

However, when I run the code from the main function and try to insert into the BT, the first node shows up just fine, but the second node becomes some big, strange number. When I run it in a debugger, it shows the number I'm expecting, but that is not the number that gets printed out. Here is my main method.

```
`
```

The problem is in my insert function, but I'm not sure what is going wrong because when I run it through a debugger, I get the expected value of 5 and 6.

Comment: Missing return at the end pf insert

Comment: `malloc(sizeof(struct Node*))` should be `malloc(sizeof(struct Node))`.

Comment: Why does `initializeTree()` take a `Node` parameter instead of just the data?

Comment: And if `insert()` will create the root node when you insert with a `NULL` root, why do you even need `initializeTree()`?

Comment: @Barmar Yes, I just realized that. You are totally correct!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In these statements

```
struct Node* node1 = (struct Node*) malloc(sizeof(struct Node*));
                                                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^
struct Node* node2 = (struct Node*) malloc(sizeof(struct Node*));
                                                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

you are incorrectly allocating memory. Instead write

```
struct Node* node1 = (struct Node*) malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
                                                  ^^^^^^^^^^^ 
struct Node* node2 = (struct Node*) malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
                                                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

The same problem exists in the function `insert`.

Also within the function move the return statement to the end of the function

```
struct Node* insert(struct Node* rootPtr, struct Node* node) {
    if (rootPtr == NULL) {
        rootPtr = (struct Node*) malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
        rootPtr->data = node->data;
        rootPtr->left = NULL;
        rootPtr->right = NULL;
    }

    if (rootPtr->data > node->data) {
        rootPtr->left = insert(rootPtr->left, node);
    } else if (rootPtr->data < node->data) {
        rootPtr->right = insert(rootPtr->right, node);
    }

    return rootPtr;
}
```

Pay attention to that passing a pointer to a whole node as the second argument is inefficient and error-prone. You could just pass an integer. So the function should be declared like

```
struct Node* insert(struct Node* rootPtr, int data );
```

Comment: On that note, in that if statement of the return function, I think my malloc there is wrong too. Let me try this. Will accept answer in a moment. In fact, I malloc wrong everywhere I called it. Thank you so much for the help!